# igraph community detection result has too much overlap

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-analysis, igraph, k-means

I have a series of points (long, lat)

1) Found the haversine distance between all the points
2) Saved this to a csv file (source, destination, weight)
3) Read the csv file and generated weighted a graph (where weight is the haversine distance)
4) Used igraphs community detection algorithm - fastgreedy

I was expecting clusters with low distance to be highly each other, I was expecting something similar to kmeans (without the distinct partitions in space) but there was no order in my results.

Question:
Why does the community detection algorithm not give me results similar kmeans clustering? If im using the same points/ distances between points then why is there so much overlap between the communities? I'm just looking for some intuition as to why this isnt work as I expected.

Thanks

Comment: DBSCAN and OPTICS are probably better suited algorithms for this. They can be used with Haversine distance (e.g. in ELKI).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work because the fast greedy community detection expects *similarities* as weights, not distances.

(Actually, this is probably only one of the reasons. The other is that the community detection algorithms in igraph were designed for *sparse* graphs. If you have calculated all the distances between all pairs of points, your graph is dense, and these algorithms will not be suitable).